# C# - If the name of an item in a listbox equals

Tags: c#

In my program, I'm having trouble writing an IF statement that see's whether or not an item in a list-box equals something, for example: if any item in the list-box equals "hi there" than it will write "Success!" to a .txt file.

Any ideas on how I would write this?

EDIT:
Figured it out on my own, couldn't figure it out at first cause I was tired.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you just learning to develop using C#, and if so, what resources are you using? Have you managed to figure ANY of it out?

Comment: you need help for the IF statement part, or the whole solution?

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough for your example

```
        string query = "hi there";
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == query)
            {
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("file.txt");
                tw.WriteLine("Success!");
                tw.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing this is a ListBox that is at System.Windows.Form, it has an Items property, which contains all the items within said listbox. You loop through it until you find what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx